# MbMenu.css doen't synchronize with the page

Tags: css, yii, yii-modules

I have a problem with the extension mbmenu YII. I set everything up properly and now I have the default theme. I want to change the theme and therefore go into the mbmenu.css and change what I need but nothing changes on the page. When I made ​​the change directly from Firefox modulates its works but changing the exact same thing in the css its not working. I've renomé the id of menu mainMbMenu but its still does not change anything.

```
<div id="mainMbMenu">
    <?php $this->widget('application.extensions.mbmenu.MbMenu',array(
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Menus', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
            array('label'=>'Gestion de menu', 'url'=>array('/menu/admin'), 
                'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Ajout de type spécial', 'url'=>array('/typeSpeciale/create')),
                array('label'=>'Ajout de prix', 'url'=>array('/prix/create')),
                array('label'=>"Ajout d'évènement spécial", 'url'=>array('/evenementSpeciale/create')),
                ),
            'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        ),
    )); ?>
</div><!-- mainMbMenu -->
```

Comment: Try to set property forceCopy to true of CAssetManager class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all published assets in webroot/assets/

Then app will republish them with new css